# Get the duplicate records based in 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table with below data (say, ORDERS table)

```
+-----+--------+---------+
| SNO | EMP_ID | ITEM_ID |
+-----+--------+---------+
|   1 |      5 |       2 |
|   2 |      5 |       2 |
|   3 |      6 |       2 |
|   4 |      6 |       3 |
+-----+--------+---------+
```

Now say that i need all the Employee ID's who bought the same item more than once. How can I do this?

I am trying this

```
SELECT O.EMP_ID FROM ORDERS O GROUP BY O.EMP_ID, O.ITEM_ID HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Waht's wrong with your query? It seems to work fine.

Comment: @EstebanElverdin: It will return a record for every item of every employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT O.EMP_ID 
FROM ORDERS O 
GROUP BY O.EMP_ID  
HAVING COUNT(distinct O.ITEM_ID) <> COUNT(*)
```